# I am getting a "Http status 500" when I am running the following struts 1x application in MyEclipse

Tags: jsp, struts-1, struts-config

here are  my files in struts application project for uploading a file. Im getting the "status 500" when i am running the code

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name />

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

struts-config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="CmdForm" type="com.intermarks.struts.CmdForm" />
    </form-beans>

    <global-exceptions />
    <global-forwards />

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/upload" type="org.apache.struts.actions.CmdAction">
            <forward name="display" path="/upload.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>


</struts-config>
```

below is the actionform

```
package com.intermarks.struts;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile;

public class CmdForm extends ActionForm {

    private FormFile ff;

    public FormFile getFf() {

        return ff;
    }

    public void setFf(FormFile ff) {

        this.ff = ff;
    }
    }
```

Below is the action class

```
package com.intermarks.struts;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//coder of the year "vinod paul"
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile;

public class CmdAction extends Action
{

      public ActionForward perform(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,

        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

        throws Exception {

          CmdForm cf =(CmdForm) form;

          FormFile file1 =cf.getFf();
          InputStream stream1 = file1.getInputStream();
          String fname1 = file1.getFileName();
          OutputStream bos1 = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Vinod/Documents"+fname1);
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    while((bytesRead = 
                    stream1.read(buffer, 0,1024)) !=-1)
                    {  
                        bos1.write(buffer, 0,bytesRead);
                        bos1.close();
                        request.setAttribute("fileName1", fname1);

                        return mapping.findForward("display");

                        }

                return mapping.findForward("success");

        }
}
```

this is the page where browse button should appear(upload.jsp)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>

<

    !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html:form action="/upload.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <html:errors />
    <br />
    Select File : <html:file property="File1" />
    <br />

        <html:submit value="Upload" />
    </html:form>
```

This is the display page (Display.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<b>The File name1</b>:
<%= request.getAttribute("fileName")%>
<br/>
<!-- <b>The File name2</b>: -->
<!-- <%= request.getAttribute("fileName")%> -->
<!-- <br/> -->
<hr/>
```

Comment: show your logs please

Comment: Logs you mean the console Stuff ?

Comment: BTW you've copied `web.xml` code in `struts-config.xml`. Edit your question and copy the `struts-config.xml` code.

Comment: Start with clean JSP to resolve errors.

Comment: Mr Krishnan, I have edited the  config file.